# Angular JS: Get subproperty from service response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just starting out with Angular and trying to adapt a tutorial I have been following.

I have a resource defined as:

```
.factory('Session', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost/api/sessions');
});
```

I am trying to use the response with a controller like this:

```
.controller('SessionsCtrl', function($scope, Session) {
    $scope.sessions = Session.query();
})
```

The problem I am coming up against is the format of the JSON response has the sessions in a subproperty as such:

```
{
  sessions: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Welcome"
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Session 1"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I get the resource to look as the sessions property?

Comment: `$scope.sessions = Session.query().sessions;` ?

Answer (score 0):

If your service is sending an object instead of an array, you should add **isArray: false** to its declaration:

```
yourApp.factory('Session', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        'http://localhost/api/sessions',
        {},
        {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false }}
    );
});
```

In your controller you can use a **callback**:

```
yourApp.controller('SessionsCtrl', function($scope, Session) {
    $scope.sessions = Session.query(function(result) {
         return result.sessions;
    });
});
```

Comment: I gave that a try, but I was getting the same error as before: Error: `[$resource:badcfg] query`. Most of the error messages I see on google indicate a further message of 'Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object?' but I am not seeing this in my case.